# Proving by definition that sequence is Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, cauchy-sequences

I need to prove by using the definition that sequence is Cauchy.
Sequence in question is
$$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n {(\arccos{1 \over k} +3k-1)\over (2k-1)^4}$$
I was confused by sum and don't know how to proceed and what to compare it with.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. We have that 
$$\lim_{k\to +\infty} \frac{{\arccos(1/k) +3k-1\over (2k-1)^4}}{1/k^3}=\frac{3}{16}<1$$
which implies that there exist $N>0$ such that for $k> N$,
$$0\leq {\arccos(1/k) +3k-1\over (2k-1)^4}\leq \frac{1}{k^3}$$
Hence for $n\geq m> N$,
$$ 0\leq a_n-a_m\leq \sum_{k=m+1}^n\frac{1}{k^3}=b_n-b_m.$$
where $b_n:=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^3}$. Now note that $(b_n)_n$ is a convergent sequence.

Comment: I don't really understand what kind of C you use. Since in the lower part you have (2k-1)^4 and you limit it with some other function of k, should't that be the same case with the upper part of fraction? How do I know that there exits that C?

Comment: @clueless See my revised answer. Is it clear now?

Comment: No, I'm not, it is supposed to be arccos(1/k). I'm sorry, it was written incorrectly in my notebook.

Comment: Fine!  Now $\arccos(1/k)$ is well defined for $k\geq 1$.